# Need help constructing a deterministic finite automata?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, finite-automata, deterministic

What are the rules for constructing a deterministic finite automata in the form of a diagram? My professor explained by examples, but I am not exactly sure what rules must be followed by all diagrams. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, in a DFA, these are the main rules, (terms specific to DFAs are in double quotes):-

- each "state" must have a "transition" for each "input" defined in the DFA
  so this means, that a transition must be defined for every input being considered in a dfa, for a state, so that one knows where to go from that state for each input.
- each "state" can have only ONE "transition" for each "input"
  well this rule is pretty self explanatory, so if you have already defined a transition for an input for a particular state, don't create another transition for the same input from the same state.

Yeah these are the ones i remember. Hope it helps. Further these points can be used to differentiate a dfa from a nfa. Other simple rules for drawing would be :-

- make a start state, indicated with arrow pointing towards the state
- have at least one final state, indicated with concentric circles to draw the state boundary
- draw the transitions as arrows
- mark all the transitions with their respective input symbols

Comment: one thing that I was wondering, lets say there was a language consisting of two inputs, {a, b}. Does the starting state have to branch to both a and b? And does each state after that have to have an a and b output or is it just mandatory for the starting point?

Comment: let me know if it helped, or if you want a better answer!!

Comment: yeah all states need to have branches for each input, start state or any state in between, or the final accepting state

Comment: +1. Good, although I don't think it's technically required that the set of accepting states be non-empty.

Comment: what do you mean by not empty?

Comment: also, how would it be possible to make a string where there are no 2 consecutive characters, if each state has a branch for each input?

Comment: when we talk about sets, empty is null, and non empty is not null, or that it cannot be null. So in my answer i had said that you should "have at least one final state", which means the set of final states cannot be null, so it is non empty. But @Patrick87 thinks it can be null, or empty. Im not sure who is right about this though :)

Comment: are u using self loops?..for one of those characters, there would be a self loop to the same state, then there would be a transition for the other input character. Can u put up your complete question here as a comment? i'll try and solve, and show you

Comment: ok, for example i need to construct a DFA that will accept the language that has both aa and bb as substrings. (the grammar only accepts a's and b's)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3781/discussion-between-droiduser-and-tehman)

Comment: check the solution, http://i53.tinypic.com/av06f5.jpg , to accepting aa and bb substring.

Comment: thank you so much, I would have went to chat but I went to bed, it was nearing 2 am here :/ but thanks again i see how you used the self loops to make the substrings possible.

Comment: is it mandatory to define transition on on every symbol? @bool.dev

Comment: @HQuser, yes, and this is also mentioned in the answer, specifically the first point: `each "state" must have a "transition" for each "input" defined in the DFA`

Comment: @HQuser, i guess you up voted my comment, which is great, but incase my answer helped you, please considering up voting it as well :) Sorry, if you find this impolite.

Comment: @bool.dev hehe yes I did voted up and also voted up your answer. I think thats the least I can do for those who take out their precious time to share their knowledge.